# Question on curried Function

Tags: scala

Just wanted to know question w.r.t Currying

If we have defined the curried function curriedNewSum

```
scala> def curriedNewSum(x : Int)(y : Int) = x + y
curriedNewSum: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int

scala> curriedNewSum(10)(20)
res5: Int = 30

scala> var tenPlus = curriedNewSum(10)_
tenPlus: (Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> tenPlus(20)
res6: Int = 30

scala> var plusTen = curriedNewSum(_)(20)
<console>:6: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => curri
edNewSum(x$1)(20))
       var plusTen = curriedNewSum(_)(20)
                                   ^
```

So why does curriedNewSum(10)_ works & curriedNewSum(_)(10) not?

Comment: Good question (although you should finish your thought at the end)... this looks like a case of Scala's local type inference not being powerful enough to infer something that seems quite obvious.

Comment: Using `_` oftentimes provokes this error for me. I have yet to detect a pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what exactly is the problem, but I strongly suspect this isn't doing what you think it is.

Try, for instance,

```
var plusTen = curriedNewSum(_)
```

You'll see it will return a `Function1[Int, Function1[Int, Int]]`. Now try this:

```
var plusTen = (curriedNewSum(_))(10)
```

And see it work! Well, that translates into:

```
var plusTen = ((x: Int) => curriedNewSum(x))(10)
```

While the other way translates into:

```
var plusTen = (x) => curriedNewSum(x)(10)
```

Something about how the function is expanding is screwing up with the type inference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why it doesn't work.  But this seems to work:

curriedNewSum(_:Int)(20)

After I thought about this more, it might be that the possibility exists of having an overloaded curriedNewSum methods

```
curriedNewSum(x:Double)(y:Int)
curriedNewSum(x:Float)(y:Int)
```

which one would be chosen? Defining the type explicitly says which method you want.

Comment: But then that should apply to second parameter too, why only first parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the type should be inferred where there is no ambiguity and that this is a bug or deliberately omitted.